# How will the data have been encoded and sent?

Tags: php, html, forms, uri

```
<form action="http://somedomain.com/login/select_from_users.php" method="GET">
User name: <input type="text" name="user_name" size="10">
Password: <input type=text name="password" size="8">
<input type="submit" value="Query">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

If this has been completed with `“John Smith”` and `“one&two&”` :

Comment: If you dont want your values to be seen in `Query String` then use `POST` method

Comment: Not clear what are you asking here. Are you asking how encoded string will look like or what browser does to get encoded string?

Answer (score 1):

will be the same as if you type following in browser adress bar:

```
http://somedomain.com/login/select_from_users.php?name=John%20Smith&password=one%26two%26
```

`space` becomes `%20`, and `&` becomes `%26`

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer set the Method as "post".If we use get method the input details that we are getting from user will visible on the URL including password,

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need to encode the data that user is going to type himself, and no one is supposed to see, except the password part of course , which is why you should use post method,

if you need the data to be passed securely to the server(from user), then what you need is SSL

if you just use **METHOD="POST"** instead, users won't see any data in URL bar if thats what you mean